# printing issue in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, printing-web-page

I'm trying to print [this page](http://www.calibredesign.com/clients/spec/index.html?view=t_fabr.html)  under the link **graded fabric ArcCom** in IE and Firefox. However, the first page that I printed out appears blank and it is not a complete content. Does anybody know how to fix this by editing the HTML or any other code?

Comment: Firefox 8.0 under Ubuntu, printed with no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reccomend creating a print stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could do tell me exactly how it works? I'm very new in css and javascript

Comment: it is a specific stylesheet that defines how you want your printed content to look (media="print"). All of the style rules would be defined in "print.css", it is handy where you can hide all unrelated content such as navigation systems and banners, then change font sizes and colors for better readability.